# How is the first choghadiya decided?

Tags: time, calendar, panchang

I've been looking at the [Wikipedia page of Choghadiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choghadiya) and while it is very clear on the boundaries between each Choghadiya, it does not tell how to determine the first Choghadiya.

Looking at different dates:

#### [28 March 2018](https://www.drikpanchang.com/tables/choghadiya.html?date=28/03/2018)

- Labh
- Amrit
- Kaal
- Shubh
- Rog
- Udveg
- Char
- Labh

#### [19 October 2084](https://www.drikpanchang.com/tables/choghadiya.html?date=19/10/2084)

- Shubh
- Rog
- Udveg
- Char
- Labh
- Amrit
- Kaal
- Shubh

While the cyclic order remains the same, the first choghadiya changes from Labh to Shubh. How can this be determined?

Comment: There is a table that monday first chaughadiya is x and Tuesday y etc you can memorize that

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Can you give a link to the table or the table itself as an answer? I've been trying to find a good reference, but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is decided by the day of the week.

#### Day Choghadiya

```
+-------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Sun  |  Mon  | Tue     | Wed   | Thu   | Fri   | Sat   |
+-------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Udveg | Amrit | Rog     | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  |
| Chal  |  Kaal | Udveg   | Amrut | Rog   | Labh  | Shubh |
| Labh  | Shubh | Chal    | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   |
| Amrit | Rog   | Labh    | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg |
| Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit   | Rog   | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  |
| Shubh | Chal  | Kaal    | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   | Labh  |
| Rog   | Labh  | Shubh   | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit |
| Udveg | Amrit | Rog     | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  |
+-------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

#### Night Choghadiya

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Sun  | Mon   | Tue   | Wed   | Thu   | Fri   | Sat   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   | Labh  |
| Amrit | Rog   | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg |
| Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   | Labh  | Shubh |
| Rog   | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit |
| Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  |
| Labh  | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   |
| Udveg | Amrit | Rog   | Labh  | Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  |
| Shubh | Chal  | Kaal  | Udveg | Amrit | Rog   | Labh  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Reference: http://www.astroadvise.co.in/choghadiya-is-simple-way-to-know-auspiciousness-of-day/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](http://astrologyfutureeye.com/astrology-knowledge/choghadiya) which refers to the timings of choghadiya:

> **Choghadiya Calculation** : - First know your local time of Sunset and Sunrise. Make hours for days Choghdiya and nights Choghdiya. Then
>   divide the time periods by eight, the result called the time period of
>   one Choghadiya muhurat. Generally, each Choghadiya muhurat has time
>   near about one and half hour.

Comment: Hi! Link only answers are discouraged. They are no longer helpful if the links are dead. Can you post relevant info from the article you mentioned?

Comment: Link that I posted is working fine.

Comment: Here I am posting Wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choghadiya for more reference. You can see at bottom in  Example section they have mentioned day and night time calculation.

Comment: Links work fine for only some period of time. They can be dead any time. So, you should add relevant information from the link which answers the question.

Comment: The wikipedia article only mention how the timings are calculated, and not the order. The question specifically asks for the order

Answer (score 0):

Arranging planets in order of revolution times:

- Saturn (30 years)
- Jupiter (12 years)
- Mars (1.5 years)
- Sun (1 year)
- Venus (7 mo.)
- Mercury (3 mo.)
- Moon (28 days)

Assign a name that signifies a primal quality of the planet.

- Saturn (Kaal)
- Jupiter (Shubh)
- Mars (Rog)
- Sun (Udveg)
- Venus (Char)
- Mercury (Labh)
- Moon (Amrit)

Weekday lord becomes first Choghadiya ruler, hence :

- Sunday (ruler Sun)(first Choghadiya Udveg) (follow above order: U,C,L,A,K,S,R,U)
- Monday (ruler Moon)(first Choghadiya Amrit) (follow above order: A,K,S,R,U,C,L,A)
  so on for other days.

This is the method for day-time choghadiya (Sunrise to Sunset)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).